# Infopath view based on the user who opens the form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have created an expense form for users to complete their expenses

Once the form has been submitted to the form library I would like to set the form so if a different user tries to open a form they did not create the forms shows a view saying they do not have permission to view the form

Here is my form

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok so Here are the Images Step by step ...

I Think now you don't want further Explanations :D

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For some reason my Form Submit button is greyed out?

Comment: if your not using Code behind with the form ...  then do this ....   1. Goto File Menu ... click on Submit Options... you will see Option buttons  .. check the one saying "Perform Custom Actions using Rules"

Answer (score 0):

Add a New Field  Form Owner .. and On Loading Event  if the Field is empty then put current user or check if the user field is current user then Show the View else show the other View of Message.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how I do that?

Answer (score 0):

[image: STEP 1 Create a Newfield Name Anything .. like User or Current User or Something]

[image]

[image]

[image]

1. Create New Field
2. Create New rule and Set Condition if The NewField is Empty then Set Action setFieldValue to the CurrentUSER.
3. Create Another Rule set Condition if The NewField is not Null and Is not equal to The Current User.. then in Action Change the view ....

Best Regards, 
Syed Muhammad Hasan Rizvi

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm really new to all this can you break it down a little more, you say I have to create a new rule but is it a validation rule or action rule etc

Comment: both are Action rules